# ASP.NET MVC Razor render without encoding using an attribute ie. data annotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is it possible to use an attribute in the viewmodel to specify for razor to render a string without html encoding?

edit: What I was asking was if it was possible to add an attribute in the model and have it modify the data representation (, like how you can add [Disable], [Layout(...)], [Required], etc.) - in such a way that it would make the html in a string render.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of, but it appears that you can change the datatype from a string to an HTMLString. If you use an HTMlString, it should render the HTML in the string.

See [Always output raw HTML using MVC3 and Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216340/always-output-raw-html-using-mvc3-and-razor)

The second response in that thread shows a possible way of using an attribute to display raw html.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Html.Raw(yourstring)`

This should help.

Answer (score 0):

**MVC by default outputs a string as plain string, not HTML.**

e.g. in your `Action`:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    var model = new TestViewModel(); // your view model
    model.Message = "<b>hello</b>";
    return View(model);
}
```

your `View`:

```
@model MyProject.TestViewModel

<div>
    @Model.Message
</div>
```

This will render as:

```
<b>hello</b>
```

If you want to actually render it as HTML, you need to change the above to this:

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.Message)
```

Alternatively, you could create an extension to make it nicer:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString ToMvcHtmlString(this String str)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        else
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(str);
    }
```

So then to render a string as HTML, in your `View`, you could write:

```
@Model.Message.ToMvcHtmlString()
```

If this is not what you're after, you should provide us with an example of where your code is falling over.